# How to retrieve data from an existing db file and display it on webpage using Django?

Tags: python, html, django, windows

This is the `views.py` file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .models import Report
import random

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
    args = {}
    data = Report.objects.all()
    args['data'] = data
    return render(request, 'index.html',args)
```

I'm finding it difficult to understand the framework since I'm a beginner. So please help me.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use class base view which will be different from function base view, to pass context data to template in class base view you need to override `get_context_data` method as below:

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    """ Home page view """
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # first of all calling it's parent class method to get context (if any)
        context = super(HomePageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # now you can update context dictionary as below:
        context['data'] = Report.objects.all()
        return context
```

Now you can access `data` in your template using `{{ data }}`

Comment: After running the code I'm getting this error- OperationalError at /:No such Column :Report.id . Can you please help in resolving this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can display the FileField content by passing the following
{{ context_obj.file_field_name.url  }} in the template.